# Mutate a list of lists of integers with specific probability

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I have the following list of integers:

```
[[0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1],
 [0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1],
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0],
 [2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0]]
```

Taking this whole list as a population and each sublist inside as an individual, like this example: 
[Population scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFGpT.png)

I need to create a function that will read the individuals and randomly mutate one of the chromosomes with a certain probability, taking into consideration that the numbers in the list can be only in this 0-3 range.

Would anyone know any method, or whatever approach to start developing this? I am completely lost and don't know where to begin, everything I tried has failed, so I am looking for suggestion how would one do it.

Comment: Why not choose between 1, 2, and 3, add, then wrap the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from random import randint, uniform;

def mutateIndividual(ind):
     if uniform(0,1) < prob: # random probability of mutation
         mutationIndex = randint(0, len(ind)) # select one chromosome
         ind[mutationIndex] = randint(0,3) # mutate
     return ind;

for i in range(0, len(population)): # outer loop on each individual
     population[i] = mutateIndividual(population[i]);
```

Exercise: You may want to modify the program to mutate a chromosome to something different than what it already is.

Comment: Hi, thanks! Actually now I am using binary sequences instead of the actual numbers, such as '[[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [6], [0]],' (only the first item in the list), in this case it would e a little different right? Since I can only mutate a 1 to a zero and a zero to a 1, then this mutation index would change, correct?

Comment: If you are using binary strings, then it would change the actual mutation. To account for this you can do the following: "ind[mutationIndex] = not ind[mutationIndex]", as if it is a 1, it will change it to 0 and vice versa. I may not be understanding you correctly but to be clear, this shouldn't affect the mutationIndex as you still need to select the chromosome in the individual to mutate.